# CKEditor 5 Angular with Mention Plugin

Tags: ckeditor5, mention

Does anyone know of a simple end to end guide of how to configure CKEditor5, Mentions in Angular?

When trying to follow the standard guides (which reference a number of different approaches) none work. I have read all of he guides on how to install plugins etc.

Cheers